# Proof relating to mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Sorry for the vague title, unsure of how to phrase a more specific one in relation to the question's context.

Anyways, here is my question:

- Suppose $f'$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f''$ exists on $(a,b)$, where $a < b$. Show that there exists a number $c \in (a,b)$ such that
  $$f(b) = f(a) + (b-a)  f'(a) + f''(c)  \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$$

1. I know you have to use MVT, basically since $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$, there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)}$. Let $g(x) = f(x) - [f'(c)(x-a) + f(a)]$. Since $g(a) = g(b) = 0$, there exists a $d \in\ (a,b)$ such that $g'(d) = 0 = f'(x) - f'(c)$.
2. However, I'm unsure of how to proceed after this part. May I know if there are any areas in my thought-process that are wrong? Or did I miss anything out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ g(x)=f(x) - [f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)], h(x)=(x-a)^2. $$
Then
$$ g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(a), h'(x)=2(x-a), g''(x)=f''(x),h''(x)=2. $$
By Cauchy's MVT, you have that, there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$ \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{h(b)-h(a)}=\frac{g'(c)}{h'(c)}. \tag{1}$$
Again by Cauchy's MVT, you have that, there is $c_1\in(a,c)$ such that
$$ \frac{g'(c)}{h'(c)}=\frac{g'(c)-g'(a)}{h'(c)-h'(a)}=\frac{g''(c_1)}{h''(c_1)}=\frac{f''(c_1)}{2}. \tag{2} $$
Combining (1) and (2) gives
$$ \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{h(b)-h(a)}=\frac{f''(c_1)}{2} $$
or
$$ f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+\frac{f''(c_1)}{2}(b-a)^2. $$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but may I know how did you get the h(x) = (x-a)^2?

Comment: Change $(b-a)^2$ into $(x-a)^2$.